# How to reference function variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Experienced python user learning JavaScript.

Let's say that I define a function that takes two arguments:

```
function alpha(var_a, var_b){
 this.a = var_a;
 this.b = var_b;
}
```

And then write a sample object:

```
function One(){
 var a = [
   ["1"],
   ["2"],
   ["3"]
 ];

 var b = [
   ["4"],
   ["5"],
   ["6"]
 ];

 return new alpha(a, b);
}
```

If I had a third function that took as its argument a function:

```
function beta(alpha){
}
```

How could I reference, in this third function, the variables from the argument function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you would have to call `beta` and pass it the instance of `alpha` the you get from calling `One`.

```
beta(One());
```

Then you can just access `alpha.a` and `alpha.b` inside it (noting that this `alpha` is the local variable `alpha` created by the function prototype's argument name and not the global `alpha` created by the function declaration).

NB: Convention dictates that you start a function name in JS with an uppercase character when, and only when, it is a constructor function. So you should have `Alpha` and `one` rather than `alpha` and `One`.

---

Let's rewrite all of that code with less confusing variable names.

```
function MyConstructor(var_a, var_b) {
    this.a = var_a;
    this.b = var_b;
}

function createInstanceWithData() {
    var a = [
        ["1"],
        ["2"],
        ["3"]
    ];

    var b = [
        ["4"],
        ["5"],
        ["6"]
    ];

    return new MyConstructor(a, b);
}

function logData(someInstance) {
    console.log(someInstance.a, someInstance.b);
}

logData(createInstanceWithData());
```

Comment: Thank you, Quentin, that was a clear and concise answer.